# Поиск с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

> "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems!" (c) Jamie Zawinski

Помогите найти всех "кошек" через регулярные выражения! :)

```
<div>let's try to find this cat and this cat</div>
<div>let's try to find this cat and this cat</div>
```

Вот это не сработало:

```
(?<=<div>)((?!<\/div>)(cat|(?:.|\n))+)(?=<\/div>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0Q5_3YvMlacj-ojM)

Второй вопрос еще интересней - найти только тех кошек, которые сидят в блоках с классом "cats":

```
cat
<div class="cats">black cat, white cat</div>
cat
<div class="dogs">black cat, white cat</div>
cat
```

Comment: Кошки, которых нужно найти спрятаны в DIVах. Остальные кошки меня не интересуют. Я могу найти только последнюю, или первую кошку, но найти нужно всех кошек, которые сидят в DIVах. Возможно такое, или нет?

Answer (score 2):

### Для первого случая:

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/16)

```
/<div.*?>|cat(?=.*?<div>)|(cat)(?=.*?<\/div>)/g
```

- **пропускает** открывающиеся `div`, или
- **пропускает** `cat`, за которыми следует открывающийся `div`, или
- **захватывает** `cat`, если за ним следует минимальное количество
  символов и закрывающийся `</div>`.

### Для второго случая

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/15)

```
/<div class="cats">|<div.*?<\/div>|(cat)(?=.*?<\/div>)/g
```

- **пропускает** открывающийся `div` с классом `cats`, или
- **пропускает** прочие `div` - целиком, или
- **захватывает** `cat`, если за ним следует минимальное количество
  символов и закрывающийся `</div>`.

**UPD:** Благодаря дельным замечаниям ReinRaus новые варианты регулярок переписаны и теперь валидны как для PCRE, так и в js-реализации. Спасибо)

Comment: **1** https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/8 **2** https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/9 и https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/10

Comment: **1** https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/11

Comment: @ReinRaus, благодарю, поправил ответ. Новые версии регулярок: **1** - https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/16 **2** - https://regex101.com/r/tB7kR8/15